# how to set foreign key during form completion (python/django)

Tags: python, django, forms, foreign-keys

During form processing I'd like to be able to set a foreign key field on a model object without the user having to select the key from a dropdown.

For instance:

```
#models.py
class AAA(models.Model):

    some_field = models.TextField()

class BBB(models.Model):
    another_field = models.TextField()
    key_field = models.ForeignKey('AAA')
```

The user will navigate from a view showing an instance of 'AAA' to a create_object style view that will create an instance of 'BBB' given a parameter referring to 'AAA'. The foreign key is set in code to point back to the 'AAA' instance.

The django comments framework seems to do this but I can't figure out how.

Any ideas? I'm sure it should be quite simple.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You can exclude the `key_field` from your model form, save with `commit=False`, then set `key_field` in your view before saving to the database.

```
class BBBForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = BBB
        exclude = ("key_field",)

def create_view(request, **kwargs):
    if request.method == "POST":
        aaa = # get aaa from url, session or somewhere else
        form = BBBForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            bbb = form.save(commit=False)
            bbb.key_field = aaa
            bbb.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect("/success-url/")
        ...
```

Comment: Ah ha! The key feature I was missing was the "exclude" statement. Previously my form never reached the validation stage because 'key_field' was a required field. Many thanks!

Comment: @paulus_almighty if this post solved your problem, you can select it as your accepted (green check on the left), same for all your other questions

Answer (score 4):

As the user creates a `BBB` via an instance of `AAA`, this should be reflected in the URL, i.e., your "create_object style view" will get a parameter identifying an `AAA` object. You can use it to get the object from the database and create your `BBB` object accordingly:

```
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404

def create_bbb_view(request, aaa_id):
    a = get_object_or_404(AAA, id=aaa_id)
    form = MyBBBCreationForm(request.POST) # or similar code
    if form.is_valid():
         b = BBB.objects.create(key_field=a) # plus other data from form
    # ...
```

(You could also set `key_field` to `aaa_id` directly, but it's probably a good idea to check if the object exists.)